# Почему Rafct сбрасывает inline стиль backgroundSize при повторной загрузке изображения

Tags: reactjs

При помощи input file загружаю картинку и сохраняю ее в формате base64 в state.
Далее картинку в виде basse64 передаю в переменную для создания объекта для inline стиля div, в котором хочу ее отобразить.
В случае со стартовой картинкой (которая загружена как заглушка), при запуске приложения все хорошо, она отображается со свойством backgroundSize: 'cover' и вписывается в div. Но когда я меняю изображение, новое почему то отображается без свойства backgroundSize: 'cover' и выходит за пределы div.

Как быть?

Для примера, когда я использовал для отображения картинки тег , все работало нормально, но картинка меняла свои пропорции, поэтому решил заменить на div.

```
// если в state есть base64 то загружаем его, если нет, то загружаем заглушку
  const pic = (base64) ? base64 : book_pic

  let divImg = {
    background: 'url(' + pic + ') no-repeat', 
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  }

  <div className = "book-picture__image" style={divImg}></div>



// так выглядит моя функция выбора файла
  pictureSelectionHandler = event => {
    let reader = new FileReader(),
        file = event.target.files[0]

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const bookForm = {...this.state.bookForm}
      bookForm.picture.file = file
      bookForm.picture.base64 = reader.result
      this.setState({bookForm})
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Природа сего явления мне так и не стала ясна.
Но решением оказалось указать background-size в одной строке с background. Теперь все работает.

```
let divImg = {
  background: 'url(' + pic + ') center / contain no-repeat',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, следует посмотреть вот здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background

> Сокращенное CSS свойство background  устанавливает сразу все свойства
>   стиля фона, такие как цвет, изображение, источник и размер, или метод
>   повтора

Из чего становится понятно, что background первого объявления переписывается background второго объявления. Потому как background - это совокупность свойств. И если переписывать это свойство "предыдущие указания" просто перетираются. Поэтому ВСЕГДА нужно указывать background-image отдельным свойство, чтобы избегать подобных ситуаций.
В идеале просто указываем отдельно:

```
background-size: ...
background-repeat: ...
и т.д.
```

Comment: Спасибо!)) Странно, только, что при старте приложения первичная картинка отображалась нормально даже несмотря на background-size отдельным свойством.